# ScaleTransform doesn't work correctly

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, tile, scaletransform, rendertransform

My idea is to create *custom Tile control* which is used as *Live Tile* (rendering it to a bitmap image and use as tile background) and within my app in a *LongListSelector*. By using the same control for both scenarios it ensures that it will look identical.

Here a short sample of my *custom Tile control*:

```
public class Tile : ContentControl
{
    public override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();

        Content = GetTileLayout();
    }

    private Grid GetTileLayout()
    {
        double width = 336;
        double height = 336;

        StackPanel panel = new StackPanel();
        TextBlock contentTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        // ...            

        Grid layoutRoot = new Grid();
        layoutRoot.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
        layoutRoot.VerticalAlignment = System.Windows.VerticalAlignment.Stretch;
        layoutRoot.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
        layoutRoot.Width = width;
        layoutRoot.Height = height;
        layoutRoot.Children.Add(panel);
        layoutRoot.Measure(new Size(width, height));
        layoutRoot.Arrange(new Rect(0, 0, width, height));
        layoutRoot.UpdateLayout();

        return layoutRoot;
    }
}
```

If I want to use it in the *LongListSelector* then it needs to be scaled down from 336x336 to 200x200 pixels. I tried it with a simple *ScaleTransform* but the result is not the same as I expected.

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="ItemList" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="222,222">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>       
        <StackPanel Margin="12,12,0,0" Background="Blue">
            <DataTemplate>
                <common:Tile VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <common:Tile.RenderTransform>
                        <ScaleTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5" />
                    </common:Tile.RenderTransform>
                </common:Tile>
            </DataTemplate>
        </StackPanel>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

This is the result:

[image]

The red rectangle is my *custom Tile control* with the *ScaleTransform*. After the transformation it should be a square again, scaled down from 336x336 to 168x168 (just an example). In the image above the height is correct but the width is too small.

It's strange because if I change the size of my *custom Tile control* to 200x200 pixels and use the same *ScaleTransform* with factor 0.5 it will be scaled down correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your `GridCellSize` is killing the transform.  Make it bigger, try (400, 400).  Also get rid of that StackPanel.

---

```
<phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <Border BorderBrush="HotPink" BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" Tap="Border_Tap" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                <Custom:Tile RenderTransformOrigin="0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
                    <Custom:Tile.RenderTransform>
                        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="0.5" ScaleY="0.5"/>
                    </Custom:Tile.RenderTransform>
                </Custom:Tile>
       </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
```

---

[image]

Comment: Yes you're right but why does it only affect the width and not the height?

Comment: If I apply the ScaleTranform to the Grid object returned by the GetTileLayout() method it does also not work.

Comment: Also, get rid of all your `<StackPanel>` it will transform it correctly. I'll update the solution in a bit.

Comment: The scaling does work now but it does not really help me because GridCellSize of 400*400 is useless for me. The items are displayed below each other like in your screenshot.

Comment: I think the problem is that the ScaleTransform gets applied when it will be rendered. So what I need to to force the Grid to start rendering.